# How can I get username and email through LinkedIn Login?

Tags: linkedin-api

The LinkedIn authentication on my website seems to be working fine. However, I am unable to get the email and name of the user when they log in or register through LinkedIn on my website. How can I get those? Ideally, I would also like to get their country. I am NOT looking for any sensitive information.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that on your developer console, under the `products` tab you have selected/enabled `Sign In with LinkedIn`. This would enable two permissions for your app

1. r_emailaddress
2. r_liteprofile

When initializing your OAuth code flow, add these scopes to your request.

The returned access token should contain the scopes you need.

A `GET` request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` with header `Authorization: Bearer {access token}` should serve you a response similar to:

```
{
"localizedLastName": "Doe",
"profilePicture": {
    "displayImage": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:DHSKSHJSJ673283"
},
"firstName": {
    "localized": {
        "en_US": "John"
    },
    "preferredLocale": {
        "country": "US",
        "language": "en"
    }
},
"lastName": {
    "localized": {
        "en_US": "Doe"
    },
    "preferredLocale": {
        "country": "US",
        "language": "en"
    }
},
"id": "HFKhsjdjd",
"localizedFirstName": "John"}
```

A GET request to `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(true,EMAIL,handle~,emailAddress))` should serve you a response similar to this:

```
{
"elements": [
    {
        "handle": "urn:li:emailAddress:73837378373",
        "handle~": {
            "emailAddress": "john.doe@email.com"
        }
    }
]}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi thanks. My site is in Bubble and I am using a plugin for LinkedIn. I cannot find any place to enter the two get requests you have shown. Any idea how and where should I place them?

Comment: @user13260019 can you provide more details as to what you have currently? Which plugin are you using?